# Rotating header text in cells in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I don't seem to be able to rotate the strings in the header cells of a pandas dataframe when exporting to excel. I have used the commands

```
rot_format = workbook.add_format()
rot_format.set_rotation(90)
rot_format.set_text_wrap()
worksheet.set_row(0,200,rot_format)
```

The strings in the cells in the top row are not rotated. However, when I replace the '0' by '1' in the set_row line, the elements in the cells in the second row of the spreadsheet are all rotated. I can send more code if required.

An alternative form I am happy to consider is to have the labels written vertically one character wide and one under the other.

Any insights would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Peter.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround to this. Anything I did to the header didn't work, so I wrote to excel without the header and skipped a row when writing to the document:

i.e.:

```
    doc.to_excel(writer, startrow = 2, sheet_name='Sheet', index=False, 
    header=False)

    #Defined the format: 
    header_fmt = workbook.add_format({'align': 'bottom', 'rotation': '90', 
    'bold': True})

    #Then I copied the names of the columns into a list: 
    header_names = doc.columns.tolist()
    col_length = len(header_names)

    #And wrote it to the header row that I skipped and assigned the format 
    #defined above. 
    for j in range(col_length):
        col = j
        worksheet.write(1, col, header_names[j], header_fmt)
```